# Disable Windows sound when some operation is performed that is not possible

Tags: windows-10, system-sounds

Scenario: I am using the Find in the [Notepad++](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Notepad%2B%2B) on Windows 10 and searching for a text inside a note. When it doesn't find it, there is a ring sound that happens.

I want to disable this sound which happens at several instances similar to the above. The software could be different.
How can I disable this sound?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You want the Sound Control Panel. There are a few ways to open it. You can get to it from the sound settings but you can also do this:

1. Press <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> to open the Run Command dialog box
2. Type `control mmsys.cpl` and press Enter
3. Go to the "Sounds" tab
4. Scroll to find the Program Event that correlates to the noise you want to remove (you can select an event and then click Test to hear the sound)
5. Select the event and change the Sound drop-down box to `(None)` (it's at the top of the list)

[image: Sound control panel screenshot]

---

The command `control mmsys.cpl` launches the Sound Control Panel directly because `control` lets you launch a bunch of control panels / settings / applets directly instead of trying to navigate to them through the newer screens that Windows starts you at. There are a bunch of other things that can follow `control` to launch various windows. I found quite a few lists by searching for `control cpl` on my preferred search engine: [Microsoft list](https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/topic/how-to-run-control-panel-tools-by-typing-a-command-bce95b4d-e8c2-1cd0-ee0d-027679d520a6), a [different Microsoft list](https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/topic/description-of-control-panel-cpl-files-4dc809cd-5063-6c6d-3bee-d3f18b2e0176), and a [LifeWire list](https://www.lifewire.com/command-line-commands-for-control-panel-applets-2626060). This can be handy if you want to jump straight to a settings panel or if that panel still exists but can't be launched by any navigation of the "normal" control panel.

Comment: Thanks a lot. That worked

Comment: Note, for me it was the "Default Beep", I disabled it and it fixed the issue.

Comment: Thanks, this was huge. Like Dave mentioned, I turned off Default Beep and that fixed both Notepad++ and Windows Powershell's annoying chimes from ringing every time I press tab or backspace.

Answer (score 7):

If wish to avoid Notepad++ sounds in particular, but would prefer to have the sound in other Windows applications, then you can use the Notepad++ setting in
`Settings -> Preferences... -> MISC. -> Mute all sounds`.